# Rails and Sqlite - rails new Example -d mysql Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

Lets say you create a new Rails app - Example using the mysql switch.
You start building away. After about 2 days you decide to switch to Sqlite for development.
What else do you need to do besides switch to the default /config/database.yml ?

That is all I'm doing now and I then get a **no such file to load -- sqlite3** error
when running **rake db:migrate**

This problem is easily repeatable. I'm using Rails 3.0.4 and Ruby 1.8.7

Comment: did you also change your gemfile with the sqlite gem and bundle install?

Comment: No. If you put that as an answer and its right. I'll give you cred. Thanks. Checking it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

answered this in the comments - whenever you switch your provider you also need to update you Gemfile as well to reflect the changes